# Getting frequent Gem RemoteFetcher::FetchError. Any workarounds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I've been getting this error frequently every day for the last few days...

```
$ gem install rails -v 3.2.1
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Forbidden 403 (http://production.cf.rubygems.org/gems/rdoc-3.12.gem)
```

My understanding based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580753/gem-install-rails-failing-any-workaround) is that this is due to a problem with the remote repository and the solution is to just wait a little while and try again. Indeed, sometimes when I wait a few hours or overnight the install command works.

However, I'm hoping for a more reliable experience.

I thought of downloading files such as `rails-3.2.1.gem` and then running...

```
$ gem install --local ~/Desktop/rails-3.2.1.gem
```

But that gives me...

```
$ gem install --local ~/Desktop/rails-3.2.1.gem 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: rails requires railties (= 3.2.1)
```

I could try downloading railties. Maybe I will. But I sense a plunge down a rabbit hole there of searching out dependency after dependency all day long.

Any alternate efficient ways to install gems? Is there something I could do through my repository specification that would allow gem installation to be more reliable?

---

```
$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails_3_for_mtc
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/ethan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails_3_for_mtc/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails_3_for_mtc
     - /Users/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org"]
     - "gem" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
     - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
     - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wound up doing was to download the rdoc 3.12 gem to my desktop (based on the original error), then installed it with...

```
$ gem install --local ~/Desktop/rdoc-3.12.gem
```

Then I ran `$ gem install rails` again, and it finished up successfully.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure your `rvm` ssl certificates are up to date.

Check their status

```
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
```

Update them!

```
$ rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

Comment: This is a very valuable tip.  I was experiencing issues with getting "bundle install" to work properly.  It kept reporting the following issue: 

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/json_pure-1.8.1.gem)
An error occurred while installing json_pure (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json_pure -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.

This resolved the issues for me!  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me, it should be the accepted answer

Comment: For those wondering, no this does not work on Linux. To be more specific the first command works, but the second one doesn't.

Answer (score 13):

You have to add the "http://rubygems.org",

but before that remove the `https` source because as it will get stuck at the certificate error and add `http` instead.

so by steps would be:

1. `gem sources` - check sources
2. `gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/` - will add http source
3. `gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org/` - will remove the https source

Comment: I up'ed because this was worked for my issue.
I was getting SSL connection issues and removing the https resolved my issue.

Answer (score 7):

Any reason for not having RubyGems in your sources? If not, add it with

```
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org
```

and try again.

Comment: I've set rubygems.org as the source. I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try leaving only rubygems.org as the only gem source. This should help.

Comment: Thanks, I did make that update, but still getting the same result.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you are behind proxy server, please ask your Internet administrator to remove restrictions from your IP.

Comment: If this was the issue, it wouldn't work for him after he waits "a few hours or overnight" to retry the operation